# Is there way to have a formula/script that could keep track of revision history on a template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was wondering if is there a way that we could have history revisions on a template.

Say a user decides to fill up a set of data in a template, Revision 1. Then, the next day, he decided to revise the data, Revision 2. But, he would want to switch between both Revision 1 and Revision 2 in a dropdown window so that the management could see the differences in revisions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to have a way to keep track of named versions of the spreadsheet that you revision in version history, if so, currently there is no direct way to perform that type of tracking, however I found this [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/115421149) that request a feature similar to what you are currently asking, however please note that this has not yet been implemented. You can add a star on the issue tracker and provide more information about how this feature will help you.